# Sublime Text 3 Emmet tab multiplication does not work

Tags: windows-7, sublime-text-3

I use Sublime Text 3 on Windows 7.

I have tried this and it works:

```
ul>li
```

But this does not work:

```
ul>li*5
```

When I click `tab` it will auto-complete to another, like this:

```
ul>li*5px
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: It's working fine for me, using a fresh installation of Emmet. What other plugins do you have installed? Have you changed any of Emmet's settings?

Comment: I didn't have change Emmet's settings. I install some snippet、ctag、git、git gutter、markdownEditing、My Snippets、Tag、DocBlockr、Clipboard Manager.

Comment: Likely it's one of your snippets that's affecting this. Try removing all of your snippets, especially the ones related to HTML, and see if Emmet works properly after that. Then, add them back one at a time and see what the conflict is.

Comment: NO. I have reset all the setting, just installed emmet, but still not working on Multiplication, I have try `div#test`, this is work.

Comment: I'm having the same troubles on OSX.  Many emmet commands work great, but * and ^ in particular aren't functioning properly.  Besides Emmet, the only packages I have installed are SublimeLinter, jshint, and PEP8...

Comment: Correction, a package re-install did the trick.  All emmet commands now functioning as advertised :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have a snippet which suffixes `5` with `px` on tab. That being the case, here is a workaround that should do the trick:

- `ul>li*5^`

Appending your multiplication with the `^` operator should stop the snippet, while still allowing emmet to function unhindered.